# How to conditionally disable proxies for some requests playwright python

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

```
try:
            with sync_playwright() as p:
                driver = p.firefox.launch(hedless=headless, proxy={
                    "server": 'fa****y.com:10000',
                    'username': 'iu***53cpeuytpna0cc7bd7',
                    "password": '**W7**Fm5',
                })
                context = driver.new_context()
                page = context.new_page()
                page.route("**/*",lambda route:route.abort()
                    if route.request.resource_type == "image"
                        or route.request.resource_type == "stylesheet"
                        or route.request.resource_type == "svg"
                        else route.continue_()
                )

                #page.set_default_timeout(100000)
               
                try:
                    url = 'https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?dsh=S-536847501%3A1663770960047319&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fconsole%2Fsignup&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fconsole%2Fsignup&passive=1209600&service=androiddeveloper&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&ifkv=AQDHYWoj7hmeMm5YT3PrA0sojYcd3nnuAx2JkCLnedM0A9sCEUG9nrlRYD-grtVE1CcBagVSvXOG'

                    page.goto(url)
                except Exception:
                    print("      [+]  Time out Error ")   
                print(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX +"    [+]  Start >>> "  + self.gmail )
                page.fill('id=identifierId',self.gmail)
                btn = '#identifierNext > div > button'
                page.click(btn)
                page.wait_for_timeout(3000)
                inbpass = '#password > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input'
                page.fill(inbpass,self.password)
                btnpass = '#passwordNext > div > button'
                page.click(btnpass)
                time.sleep(3)
                page.wait_for_timeout(3000)
                try:
                 page.locator("text=I understand").click(timeout=10000)
                 page.wait_for_timeout(1500)
                 sleep(1)
                except:
                    pass

                try:

                  page.locator("div[role=\"link\"]:has-text(\"Confirm your recovery email\")").click()
                  page.wait_for_timeout(3000)
                  page.locator("[aria-label=\"Enter recovery email address\"]").fill(self.recvery)
                  page.wait_for_timeout(3000)
                  time.sleep(3)
                  # Click button:has-text("Next")
                  page.locator("button:has-text(\"Next\")").click()
                  time.sleep(10)
                
                except:
                    pass
            


                page.locator("text=YourselfChoose if your account is for personal  >> button").click()
                time.sleep(3)
                page.wait_for_timeout(1500)
**IN THIS LINE:
(In this line : I want to make proxy stop because it's not unlimited and I am paying for GB and I want to use only local internet from this line to end is there any help ?)**
```

I want to to stop proxy usage when reach to click in 
One: for proxy usage is high and I don't need proxy anymore in the next step.
Two: I want to make it faster because proxy is slow when it reach to the page.
Please help me with code or anything I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't.

Comment: I can't open another page without proxy and close first one and keep working

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to achieve this, but there are workarounds you can use to achieve the same results using [routing](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-route). Basically, after you no longer require the proxy, you route all requests playwright makes to a handler, which subsequently bypasses proxies and forwards the response back to playwright. However, this approach will only work with async version of playwright (otherwise executing a blocking call from a route handler will block further network traffic too). Consider the below code:

```
import aiohttp, asyncio
import playwright


def no_proxy_route(session):
    """
    Bypasses any proxy and routes request directly. It's a factory function to store value of session so we don't need
    to create a new one every time.
    """

    async def route_handler(route: playwright.async_api.Route):

        request = route.request

        try:
            body, status, headers = await fetch(session, request)

        # Abort route in case of error
        except (aiohttp.ClientConnectionError, asyncio.TimeoutError):
            await route.abort()
            return

        # If no error, fulfill route with the given body and headers
        await route.fulfill(status=status, headers=headers, body=body)

    return route_handler


async def fetch(session, request, timeout=5000):
    """
    Fetch the given request using aiohttp
    """

    assert timeout > 0, "timeout must be positive"
    try:
        async with session.request(request.method, request.url, headers=request.headers,
                                   data=request.post_data, timeout=timeout) as response:
            body = await response.read()
            status = response.status
            headers = response.headers

    except Exception:
        raise

    else:
        return body, status, headers
```

Now if you want to conditionally disable proxies for some requests, you simply create a matching pattern and route all those requests through `no_proxy_route`. An example is given below:

```
### All your previous code
# .
# .
# .
# .
### which required a proxy

# Create an aiohttp session with a dummy cookie jar. This is because we will be passing the cookies
# explicitly and don't want previous requests/responses cookies to persist and interfere
session = aiohttp.ClientSession(cookie_jar=aiohttp.DummyCookieJar())

# Create a route to our handler with an appropriate pattern. The below pattern will route ALL subsequent requests to 
# handler. Remember that you can use regex for patterns as well.
await page.route('**/*', no_proxy_route(session))
```

After this is done, all requests that match the pattern, with which you created the route, will not use a proxy, even if the context has one set. But again, this is only useful if you are using the async API for playwright.